# What line do they refer to in the idiomatic expression "on the line"?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, phrase-meaning, phrase-origin

The idiomatic expression ***[on the line](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+line)*** has two main meanings according to the American Heritage Dictionary:

> - 1. Ready or available for immediate payment. (A related expression is [Cash on the line)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cash+on+the+line)
> - 2. So as to be risked; in jeopardy: "Careers were on the line once again" (Seymour M. Hersh). Related expressions are: [Lay it on the line](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/12/messages/715.html) and [Put (something) on the line](http://www.finedictionary.com/put%20on%20the%20line.html)

According to Etymonline:

> - The  [oldest](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=line) sense of the word is "rope, cord, thread"; from this the senses "path", "continuous mark" were derived.

- Looking at [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cash%20on%20the%20line%2Clay%20it%20on%20the%20line%2Cput%20it%20on%20the%20line&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccash%20on%20the%20line%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clay%20it%20on%20the%20line%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cput%20it%20on%20the%20line%3B%2Cc0) it appears that the three expressions cited above have been used especially since the 30's.
- There are different [hypothesis](https://www.reddit.com/r/etymology/comments/32w78z/origin_of_on_the_line_as_in_risk/)  regarding the origin and meaning of the idiomatic usage of "line", but none of them appear convincing.

This recent unanswered [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264479/what-is-the-line-in-cash-on-the-line-is-it-a-ship-mooring-line?noredirect=1#comment581666_264479) asked specifically for the origin of the expression "cash on the line".

Questions:

1) What is the origin of the expression "on the line"?

2) Are the two idiomatic meaning related or do they derive from a distinct meanings and usages of the term "line"?

*In other words, what "line/s" does the expression "on the line" actually refer to?.*

Comment: There are several sources for "line" idioms, some involving standing with your toes on a line, as in a military formation or a theatrical presentation, some involving gambling, where money or chips are placed on a line to place a bet.  And likely a few where the "line" refers to an assembly line.

Comment: @HotLicks - Yes, the are other idiomatic expressions which use the term "line". Here I am specifically interested in the expression"on the line" with the 2 meanings cited above.

Comment: I've always assumed a gambling origin for most cases of "on the line".  But "line" is also a term of bookkeeping, and placing money "on the line" could, in some cases, simply mean entering it into the books.  Likely there is no single source for the idiom, in all it's uses.

Comment: I would have thought the meaning of having somebody on the phone was more common than the one about having cash ready, and indeed the page you linked to has the telephone meaning before the cash one.

Comment: Imaginably from the line of a cheque where to sign, or a contract that involves risk. I put my money on the line wouldn't be quite reasonable except metaphoricly, for the number. Vice versa, name on the line, if it exists, might appear literal, or rather exaggerated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Dictionary coverage of 'on the line'**

Christine Ammer, *The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms* (1995), connects "on the line" with "lay on the line," which has yet another variant form, "lay it on the line." Here is Ammer's discussion:

> **lay on the line**  **1.** Make ready for payment, as in *They laid hundreds of thousands of dollars on the line to develop new the new software*. [c. 1900] **2.** lay it on the line. Speak frankly and firmly , making something clear. *The professor laid it on the line: either hand in the term paper or fail the course*. [c. 1920]

But Christine Ammer, *The Facts on File Dictionary of Clichés*, second edition (2006), has a slightly different take on the phrase "lay it on the line":

> **lay it on the line, to** To speak frankly. This Americanism of the early twentieth century originally meant to hand over money (from about the 1920s). However, by mid-century it meant to speak plainly or categorically, and in the 1960s acquired still another sense, to *lay something on the line*, meaning to put that thing at risk (as in, "The Marines laid their lives on the line").

J.E. Lighter, *Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang* (1997) has three definitions for phrases that include the phrase "on the line":

> **lay** {or **put**} **it on the line** {fr the gambling sense 'to put money on the line {space on a craps table for placing chips}'} **1.** to put down or hand over money. Now *colloq*. or *S[tandard] E[nglish]*. [First cited occurrence:] **1929** D[amon] Runyan, in *OED2*: My rent is way overdue...and I have a hard-hearted landlady....She says she will give me the wind if I do not lay something on the line at once. ...
>
> **2.** to explain; speak one's mind firmly and directly. Now *colloq*. [First cited occurrence:] **1944** Butler & Cavett *Going My Way* (film): Like Tony says, I'm gonna lay it on the line.
>
> **on the line** engaged in prostitution, esp. in a red light district. [First cited occurrence:] 1910 in Roe Prodigal Daughter 83: Oh if everybody did know the awful shame and degradation of such a life there would surely be very few girls "on the line."

---

**'Lay it on the line' as 'bet or spend money on it'**

The earliest Google Books match for "lay/put it on the line" in the sense of "bet on it" is from "[This 'Mere Mechanical Toy' Was Fifty Feet Long!](https://books.google.com/books?id=ESgDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA13&dq=%22put+it+on+the+line%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAWoVChMI1sji65mLyAIVyJ2ICh2U_AWZ#v=onepage&q=%22put%20it%20on%20the%20line%22&f=false)" in *Popular Science* (December 1931):

> ...how in the name of common sense could the monster be running round with a clothed young lady in its mouth? It just doesn't stand to reason unless I'm getting cock-eyed in my old age. And anyway, if by some freak of nature a girl had strayed into the dinosaur age, it's a perfectly safe bet of a million to one that she'd have been clothed in just exactly nothing or quaintly wrapped in a rapidly decomposing piece of hide. Am I right? You can **put it on the line** that I am.

And from E.A. Batchelor, "[Gasoline-Buggy Beginnings](https://books.google.com/books?id=qUAEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA58&dq=%22laid+it+on+the+line%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAWoVChMImu2h7pyLyAIVzCyICh3u-AK2#v=onepage&q=%22laid%20it%20on%20the%20line%22&f=false)," in *The Rotarian* (March 1934):

> So that good old Anglo-Saxon custom of trying to tax anybody to death if he seems to be getting along was instituted. Most of the roads were privately controlled in those days; turnpikes upon which appeared at irritating intervals toll gates where the traveller "**laid it on the line**" until it hurt. The steam carriages were just made to order for the toll-gate boys. The steam carriages were just made to order for the toll-gate boys.

And from Raymond Chandler, [*The Big Sleep*](https://books.google.com/books?id=UNPWG-zyqN4C&pg=PA50&dq=%22better+lay+it+on+the+line+fast%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMIjJO55tCLyAIVT1CICh06KQrn#v=onepage&q=%22better%20lay%20it%20on%20the%20line%20fast%22&f=false) (1939):

> "Does there have to be something else?"
>
> "Yes."
>
> She stared at me a little puzzled. "There is. The woman said there was a police jam connected with it and I'd better **lay it** [the blackmail money] **on the line** fast, or I'd be talking to my sister through a wire screen."

---

***'Lay it on the line' as 'speak plainly'***

The "spoke bluntly" sense of "lay it on the line" first appears in "[Chi Feels News Segs To Hold Continuous Sock Audience Pull](https://books.google.com/books?id=oBgEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PT6&dq=%22laid+it+on+the+line%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCkQ6AEwA2oVChMI7bnRucqLyAIVEjuICh3--QSZ#v=onepage&q=%22laid%20it%20on%20the%20line%22&f=false)," in *The Billboard* (September 29, 1945):

> Occasion was forum held by Chicago Radio Management Club. Webs don't figure on losing many sponsored programs, tho some paring of commentators was envisioned, to be replaced by on-the-spot boys—both local and national.
>
> Here's the way the boys **laid it on the line**: [Quotations from four network news programmers omitted.]

From "[What Businessmen Themselves Foresee](https://books.google.com/books?id=UgYEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA5&dq=%22laid+it+on+the+line%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDoQ6AEwB2oVChMI7bnRucqLyAIVEjuICh3--QSZ#v=onepage&q=%22laid%20it%20on%20the%20line%22&f=false)," in *Kiplinger's Personal Finance* (July 1949):

> Hundreds of letters from working businessmen have recently been received by the editor of this magazine. The men **laid it on the line**—freely, frankly, without any pose. They told how their own business was faring, and what they foresaw for the future. They were practical and down to earth. Here is a brief report on what they thought and said.

And from "[Our Enemy Is Confident; and He Tells Us, 'This Is War'](https://books.google.com/books?id=vEsEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA34&dq=%22laid+it+on+the+line%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAmoVChMI7bnRucqLyAIVEjuICh3--QSZ#v=onepage&q=%22laid%20it%20on%20the%20line%22&f=false)," in *Life* magazine (December 18, 1950):

> Our Communist enemy **laid it on the line** with a sureness and confidence which went beyond the familiar tone and language of mere propaganda. Probably the most meaningful words of the week were spoken at Lake Success by Andrei Vishinsky, the Soviet Foreign Minister. He was speaking of a mild little resolution, put up by the U.S. and five other powers. It simply asked the Chinese Communists to withdraw their troops from Korea.

---

***Conclusions***

According to *Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang*, both senses of "on the line" that the OP asks about derive from the same source: a reference to the physical line on a craps table where gamblers place their chips in making a bet. That dictionary finds examples of the two senses of the phrase from 1929 (in the sense of "to put down or hand over money") and 1944 (in the sense of "to speak one's mind one's mind firmly and directly"). Google Books searches turn up instances of the phrase in each sense starting in 1931 and 1945, respectively.

None of the other reference works I consulted offers any documentary evidence contradicting the *RHHDAS*'s findings.

---

**Update (July 4, 2022): *Early newspaper instances of 'lay it on the line'***

Slang use of 'lay it on the line' goes back to at least 1918. The six earliest instances in an Elephind newspaper database search all come from the same source: Bert Collyer, who published a four-page (later expanded to eight-page) weekly horse-racing sheet in Chicago, Illinois.

From Bert Collyer, "[Prince of India, $50,000 Beauty Is Star of Porter Stable Now at Spa](https://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=COE19180803.1.3&e=-------en-20--1--img-txIN-%22laid+it+on+the+line%22---------) in the *[Chicago, Illinois] Collyer's Eye* (August 17, 1918):

> BALUSTRADE — All the doughboys **laid it on the line** last time, but a pin-headed ride on the part of Collins sent everybody to the cleaners. By referring to that race you will have an excellent line on what the stable thinks of him.

From Bert Collyer, "['Arsenic Kid' has Another Canso in Maiden Corn Exchange—Collyer](https://idnc.library.illinois.edu/?a=d&d=COE19180817.1.3&e=-------en-20--1--img-txIN-%22lay+it+on+the+line%22---------) in the *[Chicago, Illinois] Collyer's Eye* (August 17, 1918):

> DICK WILLIAMS:—I am in receipt of a letter from Cincinnati to the effect that the commissions were down last time, but they scratched right at post time. The dope seems, "**lay it on the line**, and if any mistakes are feared we will scratch." Better string your two megs along, is my best word.

From Bert Collyer, "[Smart Clique Plants Much Kale on Game Cock First Out Says Collyer](https://idnc.library.illinois.edu/?a=d&d=COE19191122.1.3&e=-------en-20--1--img-txIN-%22lay+it+on+the+line%22---------)," in the *[Chicago, Illinois] Collyer's Eye* (November 23, 1919):

> DOLPH—270—"Brains" Anderson has had a tough job of it trying to get this bird to the trough but he is as keen as a safety razor blade right now and will cop a maiden race the FIRST rattle out of the box. Don't wait—just **lay it on the line**, then go watch the ticker.

From Bert Collyer, "['We Boys' Are Figuring on Woodtrap to Get the Hotel Stakes—Says Collyer](https://idnc.library.illinois.edu/?a=d&d=COE19200214.1.3&e=-------en-20--1--img-txIN-%22lay+it+on+the+line%22---------)," in the *[Chicago, Illinois] Collyer's Eye* (February 14, 1920):

> ON HIGH—245—Jim Robertson told me "I'm going to ride my own punk—Hopkins, then I'll KNOW how to **lay it on the line**." I like this one extra well, and by the way, please don't discount "Old Jim"—he's there forty ways from the jack.
>
> ...
>
> MEDFORD BOY—Another at the Coffroth track that is peaches and cream. Same people also have Roadmaster tuned to concert pitch. The latter, strictly a hop horse must be "hot." **Lay it on the line** boys.

From "[Kay Threatens Suit Against McClellan](https://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=COE19201218.1.5&e=-------en-20--1--img-txIN-%22laying+it+on+the+line%22---------)," in the *[Chicago, Illinois] Collyer's Eye* (December 18, 1920):

> Logan Denny, of "boot" fame, now a farmer of the Empire State, brought down a couple of trained pigs in Teacher's Pet and an unnamed shadow, said to be able to do five furlongs in nothing. Logan has the reputation of "**laying it on the line**."

And from "[Bookies to 'Cut In' at Tijuana This Winter](https://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=COE19211029.1.6&e=-------en-20--1--img-txIN-%22lay+it+on+the+line%22---------)," in the *[Chicago, Illinois] Collyer's Eye* (October 29, 1921):

> So that players who like their old 10, 4 and 2 and would rather know what they are getting than to wait until the calculators are finished, can **lay it on the line**, straight, place or show. Mexico doesn't object—and many turfites greatly favor the idea.

The next, occurrence comes from an Australian newspaper. From "[Beauford in America: Something We Did Not Know](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/128110906?searchTerm=%22lay+it+on+the+line%22)," in the *[Sydney, New South Wales] Referee* (April 4, 1923), reproduced from "a Chicago paper":

> "'How about yourself?'
>
> "'Well let me see. I've about 25 thoroughbreds, a farm,- cows, a couple of hundred chickens and two suits of clothes. That i3 not much but I'm willing to **lay it on the line** any time somebody wants to bet me there's a nag in the world capable of beating Man o' War from a mile to a mile and a half.'"

An early instance of "lay it on the line" in the sense of "predict" appears in "[Ellsworth Trio in Farewell at Tomorrow's Ball](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SCEN19250814.1.9&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN-%252522lay+it+on+the+line%252522-------1)," in the *Santa Cruz [California] Evening News* (August 14, 1925):

> The writer will **lay it on the line** that they [the Ellsworth Trio] sing to a record crowd tomorrow evening. They're going to present their numbers in both the ball and grill rooms interspersed between the dances.

An early instance of "lay it on the line" in the sense of "appear and speak publicly" shows up in "[For the Benefit of Those Who Should Know the Facts About the N. V. A. and V. M. P. A.](https://idnc.library.illinois.edu/?a=d&d=VVN19270709.2.8&e=-------en-20--1--img-txIN-%22lay+it+on+the+line%22---------)," in the *[New York City] Vaudeville News and New York Star* (July 9, 1927):

> I am not over strong and will not be for some time to come [owing to the effects of a serious auto accident], but I hope the day is not far distant when I will be able to **lay it on the line** and say, "Thanks, a thousand thanks," and then making another laydown, Ill ask to be made a member of the N. V. A. [National Vaudeville Artists Association], but from this day until the day I pass away you shall find me out in front for the N. V. A. * Mere words cannot express our thanks to you, sir, and Mr. Hough and Mr. Chesterfield and to such a wonderful organization as the N. V. A.

Whether the slang expression "lay it on the line" originated in Chicago or migrated there at some fairly early point in its existence, it was certainly well understood among horse-track habitués of that city during the early 1920s. And whether Bert Collyer coined the expression himself or merely propagated it in his newspaper, the term was clearly in use in Chicago by 1918 in the sense of "bet money."

Answer (score 0):

I have two guesses: 
The firing line, which was the line of infantry using single-shot rifles, 
or a betting table, where the bet would be placed on a line.

Answer (score 0):

not an exact match, but unmentioned:

"the line" is to trains what "the road" is to cars. My unfounded belief is that "see you down the line" derives from this. "Lay it on the line", less certain.

Answer (score -2):

The "LINE" in the idiomatic expression, 'on the line,' is the two dimensional line of geometry (ax+by=c)drawn with pen or pencil. The concept is at work in all other meanings of LINE as exemplified herein-- rope, cord, thread, path, continuous mark, row, series, direction etc.

However, the expression ON THE LINE may refer to :-

A) queue : He is waiting on the line for a ticket.

B) readily available:(as if smoothly moving on a line.

C) in risk or in jeopardy. (That is to mean not clearly one thing or the other as if someone walking on a line may fall on either side if he wavers or loses balance.

D) limit/ boundary : He is on the lines of Karl Marx.

In all, that linear concept is the driving  force of all the expressions.